# Julia - How macros are related (based on exemple from OpenCL.jl

Tags: macros, julia

I've put a discord but no result. May be here somebody could help me

When you look in the OpenCL implementation code you have two macros that seems to refer one another in some (misterious) way, I cannot see how this happens. One macro is `@check` define in `src/ macros.jl` the other one `@ocl_func` define in api.jl.
`@check` is responsible for running the `clfunc => $(esc(clfunc))`, but as far as I understood it is the `@ocl_func` macro (in the `api.jl` file)  that will ccall the clfunc.

My question how does the 'called' clfunc, for example this one:

```
@check api.clGetPlatformIDs(0, C_NULL, nplatforms) (in /platforms.jl)
```

is passed to the @ocl_func macro?

Is it implicit( because the ocl macro is define in api so every function called with api.will activate the macro, in the example it will be then:

```
@ocl_func(clGetPlatformIDs(0, C_NULL, nplatforms)) )
```

I cannot find the code which glue the two macros. Clarifying this will help me to understand how macros work.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to think about macros is that they are source-code generation tools.

> as far as I understood it is the @ocl_func macro (in the api.jl file) that will ccall the clfunc.

If you look at the [the implementation of @ocl_func](https://github.com/JuliaGPU/OpenCL.jl/blob/master/src/api.jl#L15), you'll see that the `ccall` is part of a `quote` block, that's being returned. So it's not that `@ocl_func` will ccall the clfunc, rather `@ocl_func` *generates* the source code expression which ccalls the clfunc. The `quote`d block that is returned by a macro is seen as source code by Julia and is compiled like any other code, a function definiton in this case.

So when Julia [sees the line](https://github.com/JuliaGPU/OpenCL.jl/blob/master/src/api/opencl_1.0.0.jl#L2):

```
@ocl_func(clGetPlatformIDs, CL_int,
              (CL_uint, Ptr{CL_platform_id}, Ptr{CL_uint}))
```

this gets turned into a function definition that uses ccall inside it.

Similarly, `@check` also *generates* code that does an error check and `throw`s if it's not a success. `@check` doesn't need to know about `@ocl_func`, instead both just expand into the `quote`d code that they return, so any interaction is between those generated code blocks.

> My question how does the 'called' clfunc, for example this one:
>
> `@check api.clGetPlatformIDs(0, C_NULL, nplatforms)` (in /platforms.jl)
>
> is passed to the @ocl_func macro?

The function definition for `api.clGetPlatformIDs` is generated by the `@ocl_func` macro, but once its generated it can be called like any normal function, and that's what's happening here. So there's no dependency between `@check` and `@ocl_func` necessary for this to work.

Comment: oookay I probably misused the world call (probably because of the brackets:) ) and caught myself in this mindset I know that Julia macro build code at runtime (it's not or more than a python decorator :-) )  so the function exists 
 (is written by Julia) at runtime (or compile time) and the call just happens as naturally as in a 'normal' hand written code. Thanks all for provoking this auto-reflection.

Answer (score 2):

While Sundar's answer explains what is going on it is always a good idea to try `@macroexpand` too:

```
julia> @macroexpand OpenCL.cl.@check api.clGetPlatformIDs(0, C_NULL, nplatforms)
quote
    #= C:\JuliaPkg\Julia-1.8.1\packages\OpenCL\yqbHv\src\macros.jl:3 =#
    local var"#3#err"::OpenCL.cl.CL_int
    #= C:\JuliaPkg\Julia-1.8.1\packages\OpenCL\yqbHv\src\macros.jl:4 =#
    var"#3#err" = api.clGetPlatformIDs(0, C_NULL, nplatforms)
    #= C:\JuliaPkg\Julia-1.8.1\packages\OpenCL\yqbHv\src\macros.jl:5 =#
    if var"#3#err" != OpenCL.cl.CL_SUCCESS
        #= C:\JuliaPkg\Julia-1.8.1\packages\OpenCL\yqbHv\src\macros.jl:6 =#
        OpenCL.cl.throw(OpenCL.cl.CLError(var"#3#err"))
    end
    #= C:\JuliaPkg\Julia-1.8.1\packages\OpenCL\yqbHv\src\macros.jl:8 =#
    var"#3#err"
end
```